# Ubuntu Shuts Down on Restart (v 14.04.1)

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, restart, crash

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 on my laptop and I am not able to restart it. Every time I press the restart button, the system logs me off as usual, then the ubuntu loading screen appears (with the 5 dots) and after the second dot is completed, the whole computer SHUTS DOWN. The laptop makes the sound of a HARD SHUT DOWN (like when I am holding the power button to hard shut down the computer). It appears as if the computer crashes right before it restarts.
Shut Down button on the other hand works just fine.
What could cause this problem?

I should also note that I am dual-booting Ubuntu with Windows 8.1

**Here are my specs:**

CPU: Intel Core i7 - 3630QM, 2.4 GHz

Memory: 6GB

HDD: 1TB

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.1

Graphics: nVidia GEFORCE 635M GT, 2GB

**Installed Apps:**

- Cpufreq Indicator
- Unity Tweak Tool
- nvidia-prime

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with my desktop and I fixed it magically by changing some options on my computer BIOS. Here is [my question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/552697/computer-shuts-down-imediately-after-selecting-ubuntu-on-grub/554061#554061)

My specs and symptoms are similar to your so maybe this will help you out.

Comment: I couldn't find those BIOS options you provided on my machine. However, I went ubuntu advanced options through GRUB and I selected to boot Ubuntu with older kernel (3.13.0-32). So the current kernel (3.13.0-39) seems to be causing problems. Still looking for a solution though.

Comment: Did you try to boot your new kernel with acpi=off option on the GRUB menu? During my debug saga it was suggested that my BIOS acpi was incompatible with that version of ubuntu's.

Comment: That worked! I set acpi to off in the grub menu. What is the actual problem with it? Will Ubuntu fix it anytime soon? (Also, how do I mark your comment as accepted solution. I am new here)

Comment: I have no idea why Ubuntu ACPI control conflicts with some motherboards. It's strange too because I've had this option work on and off for the same pc over the years. Also, just click on the top arrow on the upper left hand side of my comment to mark it as helpful.