# Computer shuts down imediately after selecting ubuntu on grub

Tags: 14.04, hardware, shutdown, recovery-mode

I've been experiencing a strange problem with my computer lately. When I power the computer on, it loads grub boot loader and when I select Ubuntu 14.04-LTS, the computer almost immediately shuts off.

I can only log boot the computer if I turn off my BIOS ACPI control and load Ubuntu on recovery mode, and resume a normal boot.

I'm not sure if this is a software or hardware problem. Can anyone give me some instructions on how I can start debugging?

Comment: In the BIOS health status, I saw some elevated temperatures on the CPU. I'm going to replace the thermal paste on the CPU. I'll report back in a few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a few parameters on my BIOS and now my PC seems to be working properly. My changes were:

1 - Enabled the Limit CPUID MaxVal option. The manual says "Use this item to enable or disable the Max CPU ID value limit. When suppports Prescott and LGA775 CPUs, enables this to prevent the system from “rebooting” when trying to install Windows NT 4.0."

2 - Performance mode from standard to enhanced mode, which allows overclocking. Although I disabled all overclocking options.

I can now boot with standard kernel parameters. I have no idea why this worked.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a very similar issue on CentOS.  It's not Ubuntu, but at that stage of the boot process, it's just Grub and a Linux kernel 4.x so they're equivalent for the intents and purposes of this fix.

My problem stemmed from the fact that I had recently copied all my data to a new hard drive, so all the UUIDs of my filesystems were different.  I had updated my `/etc/fstab/`, but my Grub config was still looking for the old root fs UUID.  Regenerating my Grub config solved the problem. After it booted, SELinux had to redo a bunch of things (automatic process), so if you're using that, you might see your system take longer than normal to boot on the first go.  I don't know how AppArmor behaves with this.

On Ubuntu, I believe you can regenerate the Grub config with `sudo update-grub`.

The reason the rescue system might work is because it does more advanced checks and filesystem hunts, so it can probably figure something out that Grub has to be explicitly programmed to do.

Answer (score -1):

(If I understand your question) If you can boot without the BIOS ACPI and able to boot in, you should look at the syslog.  It records everything from the very start of the computers boot cycle and what is causing it to fail to load.

```
nano /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: The file is huge. I'm having a hard time even separating the events that happened during the failed boot from the one I entered in failsafe. Should I look for anything in particular?